# Range of possible values for nth root of natural number n

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm interested in finding the range of possible values for the $n$th root of a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Right now, my intuition is telling me that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq \sqrt[n]{n} < 2$.

Do you guys think this is correct and if so how would you go about proving it? I guess you could prove that 1 is the infinum and 2 is an upper bound of a set containing all $n$th roots?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\ln n/n}$.

Comment: Can you prove it using just the field, positivity, and completeness axioms for R?

Comment: I see, you are not allowed to study the function $\ln(x)/x$ and you are not even allowed to talk about $\exp$ and $\ln$.

Comment: True, Avatar. Could you show that 2 is an upper bound, then? And yes, that's basically correct, Julian...

Comment: This isn't for a homework assignment, I'm just curious to see if you could prove the statement using just the axioms and basic analysis.

Comment: In fact, the supremeum is $e^{(1/e)}\approx 1.445$, so there is a lot of margin on the top end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n\geq 1$.

By basic axioms of $\mathbb{R}$, you can prove there is a unique $y>0$ such that $y^n=n$.

Note that the function $y\longmapsto y^n$ is increasing.

Prove by induction that $2^m>m$ for all $m\geq 1$.
In particular, $2^n>n$.

Conclude that $y<2$.

Comment: Clear enough, thanks julien

Answer (score 0):

As $n\in\Bbb N\implies n\geq1$

Taking $n_{th}$ root on both sides gives, $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq 1$

Now, using the fact that $n\lt 2^n\implies n^{\frac{1}{n}}\lt2$

Thus, $1\leq n^{\frac{1}{n}}\lt2$

There might be some tighter bounds.